# rank-one approximation for minimization of Frobenius norm out of kronecker products of unknown matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A\in M_{pq}$ be a given matrix. We want to find matrices $X\in M_p$ and $Y\in M_q$ whose Kronecker product approximates $A$ as well as possible in the Frobenius norm; that is, we want to find solutions to
\begin{equation*}
\min_{X,Y}||A-(X\otimes Y)||_F^2.
\end{equation*}
question: Please show that this can be reformulated as a rank-one approximation problem
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x,y}||B-xy^\ast||_F^2.
\end{equation*}
where $x$, $y$ are vectors and $B$ is a matrix independent of $x$, $y$. The solutions
of the former problem should be given from the solutions of the
latter, which can be obtained from the SVD of $B$.

Hints: Notice that there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $vec(X\otimes Y ) = P[vec(X) \otimes vec(Y )]$. Also notice that $vec(ab^T ) = b\otimes a$ for vectors
$a$, $b$.

Comment: The hint is wierd. $vec(X\otimes Y)$ has dimension $pq\times pq$ but $vec(X)\otimes vec(Y)$ has dimension $ p^2 q^2 \times 1$. Matrix $P$ cannot be permutation matrix, because they are square matrices.